# Запятая в сложном предложении или однородные члены?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, сложное-предложение

**Осень, осень(,) и лишь немного лета**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Запятая не ставится,](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=357)

> ...если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой
> номинативные предложения: *Слышишь? Хриплый стон и скрежет ярый!* (П.)

*Осень, осень и лишь немного лета.*

Comment: С удовольствием вижу вас на форуме, и мне захотелось немного поговорить с вами… Я, конечно, голосую за ваш ответ, он верный и полностью соответствует правилам. Для меня такой вариант тоже приемлем и  возможен, но у меня к вам такой вопрос:  а могу ли я поставить здесь запятую перед присоединительным союзом И?

Comment: На эту мысль наводит меня повтор слова «осень», оно так «задумчиво» и неспешно повторяется.  Может быть, есть два варианта, причем каждый для своего контекста. Например: (1) Осень, осень и лишь немного лета – такова обычная картина конца сентября. (2) И вот уже конец сентября.  Осень, осень, и лишь немного лета. Вот такие картинки я придумала, и мне очень интересно узнать ваше мнение. With love

Comment: Шаронушка, я ж в теории ничего не смыслю, я ея гуглю. Вариант практический может быть такой: *Осень, осень - и лишь немного лета.* Или такой:  *Осень, осень... и лишь немного лета.*

Comment: Спасибо!  Ваши варианты мне тоже очень нравятся. В конце концов, смысл – это главное, а теория изучает только форму. Вы же на практическом уровне прекрасно владеете этой формой: в книжном стиле как редактор, а в разговорном – это вообще одно удовольствие вас слушать.

Comment: "Мерси за комплиман!" (Проня Прокоповна, из фильма «За двумя зайцами (фильм, 1961)».)

Comment: За комплиман? Ну вот кто еще мне так ответит! Мы только "спасибо" умеем говорить. К тому же я без лести, все чистая правда. Пусть все знают, за что я вас люблю. И вот что еще вспомнила: «Теория суха, но древо жизни ярко зеленеет».  И если уж нужно выбирать, то всегда беру второе: "К черту я снимаю свой костюм английский.
Что же, дайте косу, я вам покажу —
Я ли вам не свойский, я ли вам не близкий,
Памятью деревни я ль не дорожу?"